# Как заменить delay()?

Tags: c++, arduino

Есть 4 метода Clock();Data();Temp();Hum();. Кусочек кода надо сделать без delay(). Как это можно реализовать? Не получается. Например сначала срабатывает Clock(),потом Hum(),снова Clock(),потом Temp() и Hum(). Код:

```
Clock();
delay(5000);
Data();
delay(2000);
Temp();
delay(2000);
Hum();
delay(2000); 
Моя 1 попытка:
void loop() {
  if (round(millis() / 5000) % 2 == 0) {
    Clock();
  }
  if (round(millis() / 2000) % 2 == 0) {
    Data();
  }
  if (round(millis() / 2000) % 2 == 0) {
    Temp();
  }
  if (round(millis() / 2000) % 2 == 0) {
    Hum();
  }
}
2 попытка:
if ( millis() - time1 > 5000)
  {
    Clock();
    time1 = millis();
  }
  if ( millis() - time2 > 2000)
  {
    Data();
    time2 = millis();
  }
  if ( millis() - time3 > 2000)
  {
    Temp();
    time3 = millis();
  }
  if ( millis() - time4 > 2000)
  {
    Hum();
    time4 = millis();
  }
3 попытка:
if ( millis() - time1 > 5000)
  {
    Clock();
    time1 = millis();
  }
  else
  {
    Data();
  }
  if ( millis() - time2 > 2000)
  {
    Temp();
    time2 = millis();
  }
  else
  {
    Hum();
  }
```

Comment: собственно основной вопрос: зачем ты хочешь заменить `delay()`?

Comment: Это у меня часы на семисегментных индикаторах. В часах посередине мигают точки и когда я ставлю delay(), все замирает и они перестают мигать. В этом и проблема

Comment: а точками что мигает прерывание от таймера? или что-то внутри основного цикла? что-то внутри какой-то сторонней библиотеки? (какой?)

Comment: Я хотел сделать чтобы точки мигали только когда показывались часы. Они расположены в методе Clock(). Код пришлось сократить. Тут только мигание точками.                                                                                                                      
 `void Clock()
{
  if (round(millis() / 1000) % 2 == 0)
  {
    digitalWrite(led_Pin, HIGH);
  }
  else
  {
    digitalWrite(led_Pin, LOW);
  }
}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я бы сделал как-то так:

```
void loop() {
  uint8_t cycle = (millis() / 1000) % 11;
  if      (cycle < 5) { Clock(); } 
  else if (cycle < 7) { Data(); }
  else if (cycle < 9) { Temp(); }
  else                  { Hum();  }
}
```

---

> `round(millis() / 1000)`

Здесь деление и так целочисленное. Дополнительно округлять результат не нужно.

Comment: Код работает, но точки не мигают почему то

Comment: @ils2, вроде всё нормально... закинь на какой-нить pastebin текущий код...

Comment: Вы в коде пропустили метод Clock()

Comment: @ils2, я заменил его на `blinkDots`, дабы время переключения было только в одном месте...

Comment: не работает же этот код, он не выводит часы

Comment: @ils2, в том виде, в котором я понимаю твою ситуацию всё должно работать... так что тут или ты что-то не так делаешь, или, опять же, я могу что-то не так понимать...

Comment: Моя цель было чтобы он сначала 5 секунд показывал часы(Clock()), потом 2 секунды дату(Data()), еще 2 сек температуру(Temp()) и в конце 2 сек влажность(Hum()). Потом опять по кругу пошел часы,дата,температура и влажность. Я хотел чтобы точки мигали только когда показывались часы, а в остальных методах не мигали, а просто горели или вообще не горели.

Comment: @ils2, с этого и надо было начинать вопрос... я думал, что это всё какие-то опросы датчиков... поправил ответ...

Comment: как еще объявить `execSec`? Не помню

Comment: @ils2, поправил...

Comment: Всё заработало). Огромное вам спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете использовать для каждого метода:

```
if( millis()-time > 2000) //2 сек к примеру
```

Comment: Я так и пытался сделать, но почему то методы работают не в том порядке как я хочу.

Comment: Что имеете ввиду не в том порядке? Можете показать как делали?

Comment: Попытки приведу сверху